# Code Composer Studio problem with fread() on c5502 chips/windows 10

Tags: dsp, texas-instruments, ti-ccstudio

Problem: fread does not seem to work for TI tms320vc5502 cpus using any code composer studio on **windows 10**.  I have tried with multiple installations to confirm this, I am currently using CCSv6.  TI does not support the product anymore, so they have not been able to offer help.

Description: When using fread, it always returns 0 and populates the buffer with garbage.  If I switch to another project with a c6713 chip instead of c5502, it works fine.  The file is certainly where I am pointing fopen to. Perhaps fopen is the real culprit, but the error manifests with fread?  fopen does not return an error.  None of the f operations return an error using ferror.

code:

```
 unsigned int bin_dat[1];
 unsigned int end_of_file;
 FILE *fid;
 fid = fopen("C:\\file1.bin", "rb");
 end_of_file = fread(bin_dat, 1, 1, fid);

while(end_of_file != 0){

end_of_file = fread(bin_dat, 1, 1, fid);//fread will return 0 at this line 
//some operation
}
```

Does anyone have experience with addressing this?  What was your workaround?

Comment: I am assuming `end_of_file` is set to a non-zero value before starting and that you actually check that `fopen` succeeded?  Is `errno` set after calling `fread`?

Comment: Well I'm pretty certain you're not intending on running code compiled for that DSP on your windows machine, right? Or what is the target you execute this code on?

Comment: Oskar, yes, but I am checking for fopen null like this: ```  fid = fopen("C:\\file1.bin", "rb");

     if (fid == NULL)
       {
          //*** Error opening file ***//
          printf("\nfopen() Failed!  was not burned successfully!\n");
          //status = FILE_NOT_FOUND;
          //return status;
       }
   ```

Comment: What does this have to do with electronics?  It looks like a pure programming problem (so far).

Comment: Oskar, I simply find that EEs are often more experienced with lower level issues like this.  It may not be semantically correct but it is under the purview of our industry as best as I can tell.  Most SEs I work with do not want to deal with this.

Comment: File IO = lower level?  I am assuming you're reading some form of ROM file on the Windows machine?  It looks like you're reading an empty file, or there's something wrong in some code you're not showing.  I don't see `end_of_file` being initialized, but I assume it is as you only have the problem reading c5502 ROMs and you can confirm that there aren't any errors after reading.

Comment: Oskar, I edited the post code to show the initialization of end_of_file.  This issue only shows up on c5502 with windows 10 machines.  I can take the same code to a windows  7 machine and it will run correctly, even with the same CCS version and compiler.

Comment: Do you know what initializing a variable means? (Your last edit only declared the variable)  // Is this code running on Windows or on the TI?  //  And where is the rest of the code?

Comment: Eh the original code inits the value right after declaration and I am trying to be as discrete as possible which is always at odds with clarity in these posts.  I'll edit the code to reflect that again.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a programming, not an EE problem, and OP has failed upon request, to explain how it is related to EE; furthermore, trying to access host files from a program running on a DSP seems like the wrong approach, but OP hasn't reacted to that either.

Comment: The OP has deleted their account. Therefore, as they will be unable to reply to any further comments nor make any updates etc, this question is being closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things first; It's been sometime since I used c5502. My CCS is updated from v6 to v9, with some pain. I had to touch a few library calls while upgrading. Some of my processors are no more supported in newer CCS updates. I assume you are using Ti's file system. I had a similar problem of "deceiving responses" from the file system. I agree with you about your question belongs to "low level". So, here is my opinion:

"C:\file1.bin" and "FILE *" looks like your code is trying to keep some compatibility with a 'host' platform.

1. Check if "FILE *" is associated correct with the library. It seems I do not use that (I need to look into more).
2. Though you see no error at fopen(), double check mounted "drive name" is "C:".
3. Further, you can trace into the Ti's file system (mine was copy of ELM-CHAN or something like) and see it opens correct, where it reads (SD card, or USB?), what it reads.

---

Edit, around the "question belongs to low level"
As an EE, when my design makes software engineers lose hairs, dragging a critical project; Instead of exchanging hot conversations in the meeting, instead of trying to teach software engineers EE stuffs, **EE is the right person to probe the hardware using a debug tool**. And, the EE, who designs the system, needs to know the low level mechanism of the firmware/software. It belongs to EE area.

Comment: I open the declaration for FILE and its stdio.h of the compiler for the c5500.  It appears to be correct, and similar to the code on the windows 7 computers -- c:\ti\ccsv6\tools\compiler\c5500_4,4,1\include\stdio.h.   The drive name for the file being pulled in is correct and is at the location placed in the code.

Comment: @nattylightfortheladies I see. And, I would suggest you to get a debug header (JTAG), and tracing into the library. Libraries are in the tools installation directory, unless in the "~/ti" (I use Linux, I recommend you to try). It feels a bit hard at the beginning, but you will soon get used to it, find issues faster. Meantime, double check mounting/attaching works right, and if the porting to your hardware platform is correct (correct platform/processor library, or custom hardware). Nudge me here, please, for updates.